# How would I query keys such that it would partially match?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Let's take this document for example:

```
{
"id":1
"planet":"earth-616"
"data":[
    ["wolverine","mutant"],
    ["Storm","mutant"],
    ["Mark Zuckerberg","human"]]
}
```

I created a search index to index the name and type, for example if searched for name:wolverine or type:mutant I'd get the document that has it. But as per my requirement **I don't want the whole document, I only want `["wolverine","mutant"]`** I've created a view that outputs as:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "key":"earth-616",
    "value":["earth-616","wolverine","mutant"]
}
```

Then I found out I can query only with keys. (Is it possible to create search indexes on views?, Couldn't find anything in the documentation)
Or should I create views along with the one above like this:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "key":"wolverine",
    "value":["earth-616","wolverine","mutant"]
}
```

And

```
{
    "id":,
    "key":"mutant"
    "value":["earth-616","wolverine","mutant"]
}
```

This way I can query with keys that I want but I can't seem to partial match keys(Am I missing something?)

Comment: Could  you define what is a search index? Are you referring to Lucene Text search? Also, with your current data structure, the type of query that you want to achieve will be hard. Maybe something like this : people : [{"name":"wolverine","race":"mutant"}] would be cleaner and easier to query

Comment: @AlexisCôté Yes I'm referring to Lucene Text Search. "people : [{"name":"wolverine","race":"mutant"}]" is way more cleaner I agree, but this is what I **have** to work with. The best solution I came up with so far for this purpose, would be to index every substring of an  key. Is that a bad idea? I'am very new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the output to be exactly as described then I believe you have to use views, and to support wildcard searches I believe you will have to index every substring of a key.

One alternative is to use Cloudant Query, although admittedly you cannot get the exact output you are looking for. If you issue a query like so:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": 0
    },
    "data": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "$regex": "(?i)zuck"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "data"
  ]
}
```

The result will be the entire data array:

```
{
  "data": [
    ["wolverine", "mutant"],
    ["Storm", "mutant"],
    ["Mark Zuckerberg", "human"]
  ]
}
```